# What is the difference between using generics and interfaces in methods and classes

Tags: java, generics, interface, type-erasure

I'm wondering what is the difference between using an interface (or a supertype) in a generic class or method and using the generic approach with bounding (T extends Interface).

Let's say that I have two classes that implement and interface (naive examples):

```
public interface MeasurableDistance {
    public Point getPosition();
}

public class Person implements MeasurableDistance {
    private Point position;

    public Point getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}

public class House implements MeasurableDistance {
    private Point position;

    public Point getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

1) What would be the difference between writing a method in the following ways:

```
public int computeDistance(MeasurableDistance a, MeasurableDistance b) {
    Point a = a.getPosition();
    Point b = b.getPosition();
    //compute distance
    return distance,
}
```

and something like

```
public <T extends MeasurableDistance, S extends MeasurableDistance> int computeDistance(T a, S b) {
    Point a = a.getPosition();
    Point b = b.getPosition();
    //compute distance
    return distance,
}
```

2) And if I wanted a class to hold a MeasurableDistance object:

```
public class Holder {
    private MeasurableDistance holder;

    public Holder() {};
    public add(MeasurableDistance a) {
        holder = a;
    }
}
```

or something like

```
public class Holder<T extends MeasurableDistance> {
    private T holder;

    public Holder<T>() {};
    public add(T a) {
        holder = a;
    };
}
```

For 1, I think they should be pretty much identical, right? Obviously calling the non generic version

```
Person a = new Person();
Person b = new Person();
House c = new House();
House d = new House();
computeDistance(a,c);
computeDistance(a,b);
computeDistance(c,d);
```

would always work because computeDistance() would be seeing those objects as MeasurableDistance because of polymorphism. The generic version instead should work too right? The compiler would infer the MeasurableDistance type and add casts accordingly. Even if I wanted to call it this way:

```
<Person, House>computeDistance(a,c);
```

it would have the same effect, the method would look like

```
    Point a = (MeasurableDistance) a.getPosition();
    Point b = (MeasurableDistance) b.getPosition();
```

if I'm not mistaken. Or, now that I think about it, it should look like this:

```
    Point a = (Person) a.getPosition();
    Point b = (House) b.getPosition();
```

and it would work because both Person and House are implementing that method.

So what would be the advantage of the generic method? I've read that it's typesafe because casts are always right, but with the non generic method you won't have casts at all.

Comment: 1) There is no point in using the generic there. All you need is a pair of `MeasurableDistance` instances. The only way in which you can use the generic is if you have a generic parameter (or generic or non-generic return) type which is in some sense related to the inputs, e.g. `List<T>`.

Comment: @JornVernee thank you, fixed it!

Comment: @AndyTurner could you expand on your comment please? The second part especially. Thank you!

Comment: you can't do anything with these parameters that you couldn't do to a plain `MeasurableDistance`. The only advantage would be if you wanted to get a more-specifically typed return value (e.g. `Person p = max(personA, personB);`, rather than `MeasurableDistance p = max(personA, personB);`, for some definition of "max"); or if you want to pass a generic instance (e.g. a list: `addToContainer(listOfPeople, person);`, where `listOfPeople` is of type `List<Person>`).

Comment: When we use an interface that means, it possible to have a lot of implementation of an algortihm , eg : getPosition() from gps, satelit ...
But generics classes are used to write a reuse code for a set of classe.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing the reason to use generics, with the reason to use bounded generics.

A reason for using bounded generics, implies that there is already a reason to use generics.

Let me recap.

---

The reason to use generics is explained in the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), and one of the most visible reasons is this:

> The following code snippet without generics requires casting:
>
> ```
> List list = new ArrayList();
> list.add("hello");
> String s = (String) list.get(0);
> ```
>
> When re-written to use generics, the code does not require casting:
>
> ```
> List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
> list.add("hello");
> String s = list.get(0);   // no cast
> ```

---

The reason to use bounded generics is separate from the reason to use generics. **If you have a reason to use generics**, using bounds let's you *require* a certain level of functionality of a type:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    ...
    public void disposeAll() {
        for(T e : list)
            e.dispose(); // compile time error
    }
}
```

The above error can be solved by adding a bound:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Disposable> {...}
```

---

The cases that you have shown don't actually have a reason to use bounded generics, like you have pointed out. But this is because they don't have a (good) reason to use generics in the first place.

In case 2, generics let you limit the type of object that can be held by `Holder`:

```
Holder<House> holder = new Holder<>();
holder.add(new Person()); // compile time error
holder.add(new House());
```

Which isn't very useful. There is no real reason to use generics there.

But if you were also retrieving the value, generics would be useful:

```
Holder<House> holder = new Holder<>();
// holder.add(new Person());
holder.add(new House());
House h = holder.get(); // no cast
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you define a method like

```
public <T extends MeasurableDistance, S extends MeasurableDistance>
    int computeDistance(T a, S b) {

    Point a = a.getPosition();
    Point b = b.getPosition();
    //compute distance
    return distance,
}
```

There will be *no type cast* at all. This method will do exactly the same as with the method signature

```
public int computeDistance(MeasurableDistance a, MeasurableDistance b)
```

which is the reason why the generic type parameters make no sense here; they don’t change anything.

---

As a rule of thumb, type parameters on methods are useful when you want to declare a relationship between two or more parameters or between parameter(s) and the return type.

```
public <T extends MeasurableDistance> T validate(T a, Rectangle area) {
    Point p = a.getPosition();
    if(!area.contains(p))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return a,
}
```

Here, we have a relationship between the parameter and return type, which allows use to use it like:

```
Person person;
Rectangle localArea;

public void setPerson(Person newPerson) {
    this.person = validate(newPerson, localArea);
}
```

because the generic signature specifies that when we substitute `Person` for `T`, we have to pass in a `Person` instance and are guaranteed to get back a `Person` instance.

---

Likewise, generic signatures at classes are useful, if we can express a relationship between two or more members of the class. E.g. a `List` expresses such relationship as the type of the objects we `add` or `set` is the same type we can retrieve via `get`.

So your `Holder` class would be an appropriate use case for a type parameter, when you add a method to retrieve the encapsulated object, as then, there is a relationship between the storage and retrieval methods. As a consequence, there is also a relationship between these two methods and the type of the member variable holding that reference, which is required for correctly implementing the logic.